# Calling a function on an object if not null

Tags: c#, generics, null, lambda

Here is code for check `null` in object:

```
public static TResult IfNotNull<TInput, TResult>(this TInput obj, Func<TInput,TResult> expression)
    {
        if (obj == null || expression == null) return default(TResult);
        var value = expression(obj);
        return value;
    }
```

The above code is best pratice of check nullability in object.  I'm working on c# V4.0.

Example usage :

```
Person.IfNotNull(x => x.User).IfNotNull(x => x.Name) ?? "";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be sure it always works you should add a constraint to the method:

```
where TInput : class
```

This will ensure that `TInput` is a reference type.

It makes no sense to call it on structs. For them, you need another overload with a different constraint and some `?` question marks:

```
public static TResult IfNotNull<TInput, TResult>(
     this TInput? obj, 
     Func<TInput, TResult> expression
) where TInput : struct
{
    if (!obj.HasValue) return default(TResult);
    var value = expression(obj.Value);
    return value;
}
```

Someone may ask at this point: but why do we need two extensions if theoretically a single one does the job too?

Consider this:

```
((decimal?)2).IsNotNull(x => x.Value * 2)
```

With a single extension you need to use the `.Value` property for nullable types. With two extensions you get a clean value so you just do

```
((decimal?)2).IsNotNull(x => x * 2)
```

But isn't this just a convenience? Of course it is. Don't we write extensions  exactly for that reason?

---

As a matter of fact I use a similar code myself:

```
public static TResult IIf<TArg, TResult>
(
    this TArg arg,
    Func<TArg, bool> predicate,
    Func<TArg, TResult> ifTrue,
    Func<TArg, TResult> ifFalse = null
)
{
    if (predicate == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate)); }
    if (ifTrue == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ifTrue)); }

    return predicate(arg) ? ifTrue(arg) : (ifFalse == null ? default(TResult) : ifFalse(arg));
}
```

but you can create a simplified version of your method and combine it with the `IIf`

```
public static bool IsNotNull<TInput>(this TInput obj) where TInput : class
{
    return obj != null;
}
```

to do this

```
Person
    .IIf(p => p.IsNotNull(), p => p.User)
    .IIf(u => u.IsNotNull(), u => u.Name, u string.Empty);
```

Comment: There's no need for the `class` constraint.  The method will work just fine for nullable structs when just using the OP's method.  There's also no real reason to *prohibit* the method from being called on a non-nullable value.  Yes, it's pointless, but it's still entirely functional.  There's nothing gained from your alteration.

Comment: @Servy ok, noted but you should know that there is a reason why the constraint makes sense, especially for nullable types; consider this:`((decimal?)2).IsNotNull(x => x.Value)` here you need to explicitly use the `.Value` property because it passed it _entirely_. With an additional extension you get a _clean_ value without `x.Value`.

Comment: Okay, you can potentially omit some number of calls to `Value`.  The point remains that you specifically said that your transformation is necessary, when in fact it's only a very mild possible convenience.  Big difference.

Comment: @Servy I understand your point. I should have mentioned it. Somehow I thought it was obvious since I used the expression`obj.Value` there. Of course it's a convenience, all extensions are about convenience. I'll add this additional example another time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C# 6 it would be much cleaner to just use the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx), `?.`:

```
Person?.User?.Name
```

This will return `null` if either `Person`, `User` or `Name` is `null`.

If you're not using C# 6 you should strongly consider upgrading to the current version of Visual Studio (2015). You can continue to target .Net 3.5 while still benefitting from the many new features and improvements developed over the past 5+ years.

Comment: The OP writes: _I'm working on c# V4.0._

Answer (score 1):

Your way seems just fine.

One thing to note is that I would throw an exception if a null "expression" parameter was provided - it is a better practice to do so, since it is not "acceptable" that the expression parameter would be null.
There's a standard .NET exception for this (System.ArgumentNullException).

Also, consider renaming "expression" to "selector" - it is a common name for projection delegates in .NET

Answer (score 1):

Not much to talk about the code as it's pretty short and readable rather your name is bad for such function it's not descriptive at all. It returns `default()` if the some of the parameters is null else it returns the expected result , most of the standard methods that have the same logic usually end like this **OrDefault** e.g **FirstOrDefault**. You can maybe call it **ExpressionOrDefault**.

You might also want to add some constraints to the generic parameter maybe let `where TInput : class` as value type variables can't be null anyway.